# I'm trying to include a form in a lightbox using html

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, lightbox

I'm working on a project to select some options according to the picture showing on the side. These options are about size, colors...

Basically, I'm trying to show the picture on a lightbox (which is working fine), but I'm trying to put next to the picture a white background with a form with some options and action buttons. When I try to do it, it actually doesn't work as it should.

I'm using this function

```
var placeImage = function(x) {
var img="";
for (var counter = 0; counter <= x; counter++ ) {
     img += '<a href="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x80'+counter+'.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img class="img-responsive gallery__img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x80'+counter+'.jpg" alt="" />';
}
    document.getElementById("placing_img").innerHTML = img;
};
placeImage(10);
```

HTML

```
<div id="placing_img"></div>
```

It shows 11 pictures in my gallery, and as I'm using the Lightbox function, it's working really fine when I click on it.

I would like to open it and the picture shows on the right and the form shows on the left with some options and button.

The question is, is it possible?

Thank you and I'm trying to learn more about CSS, HTML and JS. I'm still a beginner on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
        .some-page-wrapper {
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            /* background-color: red; */
        }

        .row {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .column {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: 10px;
            flex-basis:100%;
            flex: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='some-page-wrapper' id="placing_img">
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var placeImage = function(x) {
// var img="";
for (var counter = 0; counter <= x; counter++ ) {
    // '<a href="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x80'+counter+'.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">
     img = '<img class="img-responsive gallery__img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/1000x80'+counter+'.jpg" alt="" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain"/>';
    var h = `<div class='row'>
            <div class='column'>
                ${img}
            </div>
            <div class='column'>
                <form style="background-color:yellow; height: 100%;">
                    <input type=text>
                    <button>button${counter}</button>
                </form>    
            </div>
        </div>`;    
        document.getElementById("placing_img").innerHTML += h;
}
    
};
placeImage(10);
</script>
<html>
```